# Story identification. Planet on neighbouring solar system to Red Giant

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to identify a story that I read before 2000, probably before 1990

The setting was a planet which orbited a "normal" star but was close to a red giant (which dominated the night sky and was bright enough to cast shadows.  The inhabitants (humans? humanoid aliens?) had a bittersweet relationship to the red star, which was central to their mythology but which they knew (had recently discovered) could supernova any day.  There was a sense that they were living on borrowed time. I think in the last scene the star was observed to be suddenly brightening, suggesting that the supernova was beginning.

I think it was in a collection from the library.

Comment: @BenCrowell There are at least 3 ways to handwave that: first that the red giant formed much later, secondly that in a 10My lifespan a star with a radial velocity of 100km/s could have traveled over 3000ly, thirdly it could actually be a Type Ia supernova on a faint companion to the red giant.

Comment: @BenCrowell I don't recall that.  I'd guess it was just handwaved. I don't think it was very "hard" sci-fi. But note that the "sun" was a normal "yellow sun".  The red star was in a neighbouring star system, so several light-years away, but the supernova was going to destroy the atmosphere or something. Theres a question on astronomy.se that reminded me of this https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/35137

Comment: This might already have been answered at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/191555/book-where-planets-star-explodes-some-escape-on-giant-ships-and-eventually-fin

Comment: It might have been an extract of the first part of that story.

Comment: Oops, I didn't read the question carefully enough. Deleting my earlier comment.

Comment: *All the Stars a Stage* is a poor match, but I wonder if it was based on or at least inspired by the short story the OP is thinking of. I had a look through my collections of Blish's short stories but without finding any obvious match.

Comment: There are similarities to *The Mote in God's Eye* and *The Gripping Hand*, but in neither of those does the red giant star go supernova.

Comment: It couldn't be a Superman story, could it? I vaguely recall a similar story in which the threatened planet was Krypton.